# How to not add to the list, when the return of a LINQ IEnumerable is empty?

Tags: vb.net, linq, ienumerable

**I do have the following VB.NET code:**

```
    Dim list = directoryQuery.Select(
            Function(d) New With {
                .dir = d.FullName,
                .acl = GetFileSystemAccessRule(d).Select(
                                Function(a) New With {.if = a.Reference.ToString()}
                )
            }
    )
End Sub
```

Sometimes the return of `GetFileSystemAccessRule(d).Select` is `Return Enumerable.Empty(Of FileSystemAccessRule)()`. In that case, I would like to neither add `.directory` nor `.acl` to that `list`. I want to skip it.

So I tought about the options to remove afterwards the empty items.

```
//tried but failed:
list = list.Where(Function(a) a.acl IsNot Enumerable.Empty(list)).ToList()
//tried but failed:
list = list.Where(Function(a) a.acl IsNot Nothing).ToList()
```

But unfortunately all of them failed. What do I wrong?

Comment: can you try `list = list.Where(Function(a) a.acl IsNot Nothing)`

Comment: thank you for the reply, it didn't change anything in the list.

Comment: maybe you can take a look to this : [Walkthrough: Implementing IEnumerable(Of T) in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/control-flow/walkthrough-implementing-ienumerable-of-t)

Comment: The line `If arrRules(i).IsInherited.ToString() = False` suggests to me that it isn't using `Option Strict On`. Use that, and the error messages might lead you to a solution.

Comment: didn't help me to find the answer of my question, but to fix another mistake. thank you @Andrew Morton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be the way to go:

```
list = list.Where(Function(a) a.acl.Any())
```

or something closely resembling that (I'm not very well versed in VB.NET syntax).

Comment: wooow, searched for few hours. With `.Any()` it works! Thanks a lot! 
[Enumerable.Any Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0)